# Линии уровня seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Всем привет! Хочу построить линии уровня по pandas dataframe.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['md_value', 'est_value', 'auc_roc_value'])
```

Первые два столбца: значения параметров, третий столбец - значение метрики.

Идея в том, что должен получиться некоторый фронт, который будет обеспечивать одинаковую метрику при разных сочетаниях md_value и est_value, эти комбинации как раз записаны в result и для каждой комбинации посчитана метрика.
Пробовал использовать seaborn kdeplot, но не получилось.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать, чтобы разобраться.

Comment: что есть "линии уровня" и "фронт" в контексте Pandas и Seaborn? Можете привести небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных и ожидаемый результат в вопросе? Пока что ничего непонятно...

Answer (score 0):

Если я понял правильно, то попробуйте для начала диаграмму рассеяния. В вашем случае картина должна получиться более осмысленная, чем со случайными данными:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

n = 1000
result = pd.DataFrame({'md_value': np.random.randn(n), 'est_value': np.random.randn(n), 'auc_roc_value': np.random.random(n)})
sns.scatterplot(x='md_value', y='est_value', hue='auc_roc_value', data=result);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, вы поняли правильно, это почти то, что нужно, но хотелось бы наложить график линий уровня, где каждый уровень - как раз отдельное значение auc_roc_value.